# Error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/tools/idea/logcat/AndroidLogcatService" when installing my plugin in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, plugins, android-gradle-plugin, logcat

I developed a plugin. And I’m trying to install it on Android Studio. I get this IDE error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/tools/idea/logcat/AndroidLogcatService

This is the `depends` tags in my *plugin.xml* file:

```xml
    <depends>com.intellij.modules.platform</depends>
    <depends>com.intellij.modules.androidstudio</depends>
    <depends>org.jetbrains.android</depends>
```

#### File *build.gradle.kts*

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.7.20"
    id("org.jetbrains.intellij") version "1.12.0"
}
intellij {
    version.set("2022.3.3")
    type.set("IC") // Target IDE Platform
    updateSinceUntilBuild.set(false)
    plugins.set(listOf(/* Plugin Dependencies */
        "android",
        "gradle"
    ))
}
    runIde {
        ideDir.set(file("/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents"))
    }
```

#### Important error lines

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/tools/idea/logcat/AndroidLogcatService


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.tools.idea.logcat.AndroidLogcatService PluginClassLoader(plugin=PluginDescriptor(name=PlugiTest06, id=com.example.PlugiTest06, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2022.3/plugins/PluginTest06, version=1.0-SNAPSHOT, package=null, isBundled=false), packagePrefix=null, instanceId=125, state=active)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

I don’t know why I get this error and I’m using the same version for [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) and Android Studio.

I’m guessing we need to add another depend tag which gives us access to the *AndroidLogcatService* class or add something to [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) which provide the same purpose for me.

Answer (score -1):

The error you're encountering suggests a `NoClassDefFoundError` for `com/android/tools/idea/logcat/AndroidLogcatService`. This usually occurs when your plugin is trying to use a class that is not available during runtime.

Firstly, ensure that you are using the correct versions for the dependencies. Make sure that the versions specified in your `plugin.xml` and `build.gradle.kts` files are compatible with each other.

Next, since your plugin relies on Android-related classes, you might need to add a dependency on the Android Gradle plugin in your `build.gradle.kts` file. Update your `plugins` block to include the Android Gradle plugin like this:

kotlin

```
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.7.20"
    id("org.jetbrains.intellij") version "1.12.0"
    id("com.android.library") version "7.0.0" // Add this line
}
```

Make sure to adjust the version number according to the version of the Android Gradle plugin you want to use.

If the issue persists, you may need to look into the classpath and dependencies more closely. Sometimes, conflicts or missing dependencies can cause such runtime errors. You can check the dependencies and their versions using the following Gradle command:

```
bash
./gradlew dependencies
```

This command will display the dependency tree, and you can analyze if there are any conflicts or missing dependencies related to Android.

Additionally, ensure that your plugin is compatible with the specific version of Android Studio you are using. Sometimes, updating or downgrading your plugin or Android Studio version can resolve compatibility issues.

If none of these solutions work, consider reaching out to the Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA plugin development communities for more specific assistance. They may be able to provide insights or solutions based on their experience with plugin development for these IDEs.

Comment: it does not work for me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that use of AI Tools (e.g., ChatGPT) to generate or reword content that you post [is not permitted](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) on Stack Overflow, even if you've validated this content. Also see the related [Help](/help/ai-policy) on this topic. We do hope you'll stick around and become a valuable member of the community by contributing your own quality answers and questions in the future!